# My iPhone was stolen a week ago i just noticed now and turned on find my iphone

Tags: iphone, icloud

Will Icloud lock turn on even if the theif has reset the phone already?

Answer (score 1):

If the thief resets the phone, they still cannot disable iCloud Activation lock.  They would need your password to do that.

The only way to disable that is to disable Find my iPhone before the reset by entering your iCloud password or at the startup process by doing the same.

Comment: i think i turned find my iphone on after he reset tho. will he icloud lock still turn on after the reset?

Comment: If he had it in his possession, you cannot remotely turn find my iPhone on.

It had to be on before he reset the phone.

Comment: so if he had reset it already and i then turned find my iphone on... the i cloud lock wouldnt turn on??

Comment: What I'm saying is that you can't turn on find my iphone remotely.  If he still had possession of the phone with no find my iPhone, you could not re-activate it without having the device in your possession.

Comment: no no no. I have two ipads linked with the same i cloud account. i turned on find my iphone from the ipad. so what i'm saying, is that if the theif has already factory reset the iphone. will i cloud lock turn on. because i think he already reset it.

Comment: No - you cannot turn on iCloud Lock form another device.  iCloud lock must be turned on from the iPhone itself which is not in your possession.

Comment: so how would i be able to turn icloud lock on in the first place??

Comment: iCloud lock is turned on via turning on Find my Iphone directly within Settings from the iPhone.